# Most Efficient Way to Use 'reduceRegions' in Google Earth Engine on a Very Large FeatureCollection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am working with 1 meter NAIP imagery on Google Earth Engine. I am trying to use reduceRegions to extract point values from NAIP using an ee.FeatureCollection that contains several thousand points for use in a classification problem. But if I try and use 'reduceRegions' at NAIP's native 1 meter resolution, the operation fails.

Fails: *Error: Execution failed (internal error).*

```
var REGION_BOUNDARY = ee.FeatureCollection('ft:1fRY18cjsHzDgGiJiS2nnpUU3v9JPDc2HNaR7Xk8')
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('Name', 'Kansas'));

var training_pts = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(
  REGION_BOUNDARY, 
  90000);

var estNDVI = function(image) {
  var ndvi = image.normalizedDifference(['N', 'R']).rename('NDVI');
  return image.addBands(ndvi);
};

var naip = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
  .filterBounds(REGION_BOUNDARY) // this is a US state, e.g., Kansas
  .filterDate(String(YEAR-2), String(YEAR));

var naip_ndvi = naip.map(estNDVI).mean();

training_pts = naip_ndvi.reduceRegions(
  training_pts, 
  ee.Reducer.mean(), 
  1 // scale parameter
);
```

Edit: User [Kersten](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/39299/kersten) says that the size of the FeatureCollection is the issue.

Comment: Are you certain this example contains all the relevant code parts? Reproducing it with some points in Texas works fine: https://code.earthengine.google.com/0c29392cf9e7bd8f96e416a20bc7983d

Comment: Hi Kersten. Thanks for poking around. Your example had a few points for the pandhandle of Texas. The project region I'm looking to make inference about is a little larger and the number of points I'm working with is in the hundred thousand points range. Using Kansas as an example, that's 90000/2.13099e+11 square-meters available for sampling. I updated the code to clarify.

Comment: I suspect your error is linked to the amount of randomPoints you are trying to create. With 900 points for instance it was working flawlessly. May I ask why that many? If they are uniformely distributed wouldn't it make a lot more sense to calculate the pixel-wise mean for all of Kansas (depending on what you aim to do with it further on).

Comment: Sure. These are training points going into a random forests model. The points are eventually filtered down using NASS-CDL/NLCD to balanced classes representing forest, grassland, crops, etc. And  then merged with a digitized dataset for a locally-invasive woody species I am working on. Each class ends up with around 2000 values after filtering. But there are some cover classes that have a small footprint in many US states -- 'small grains' for instance. So I have to generate a lot more points than I will actually use to ensure that at least 2000 are available for model fitting.

Comment: Still curious about what's happening with the 'scale' parameter as well. Does reduceRegions honor that parameter and use cached imagery at a different scale than the native 1 meter NAIP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a) I don't think that error message corresponds to the script you've included, since the script has no kernel operations.  Is the script incomplete, or was that error message from a different version of it?

b) Rather than over-sampling, have you tried using `Image.stratifiedSample()`?  e.g.

```
var naip = ee.ImageCollection("USDA/NAIP/DOQQ")
  .filterDate(String(YEAR-2), String(YEAR));

var naip_ndvi = naip.map(estNDVI).mean()
      .addBands(ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011'), ['landcover']);

var training_pts = naip_ndvi.stratifiedSample({
  numPoints: 2000,
  classBand: 'landcover',
  region: REGION_BOUNDARY,
  scale: 1
});
Export.table.toDrive(training_pts);
```

c) Even with stratifiedSample() you should expect this to take quite a while; at 1m resolution Kansas is over 200B pixels, and picking though those to find 2000 with some of the less-frequently occurring classes is a lot of data to process.  Are you sure you'll get better results with 1m than (say) 8m, which would reduce the amount of data to be processed dramatically?  Keep in mind that NLCD only has 30m resolution.

d) Another benefit of stratified sampling:  note that

```
print(ee.Image('USGS/NLCD/NLCD2011').select('landcover').reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
  geometry: REGION_BOUNDARY,
  maxPixels: 1e9
}));
```

shows the least frequent class (42) only represents 0.016% of the pixels, so even with 90,000 random samples you'd only expect to get 14 in that class.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. This helps clean-up half of my problem and stratifiedSample() is what I was looking for.  I only use the broad categories in NASS/NLCD that are prevalent across the plains (grass/forest/row crops). So 90K worked. But, I was down-sampling everything with calls to filter(), to get balanced classes. Which is  inefficient. Still limitations to calling reduceRegions() on 1 meter NAIP with a large number of point features. But I think this is just a technical limitation on EE that I won't be able to resolve. Just aggregate 1-meter NAIP up to whatever works for your proj extent.